# Text Editor Issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add text editor with execCommand() and applying contenteditable="true" to div. It is working fine for bold and italic, but when I click to normal it normalizes the selected text, but when I click to normal it does not write normalize text rather it writes in bold and italic. What I need is to write to normalize text after clicking on the normal button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.user_editor_block li', function(){    
    var test = $(this).text()
    if (test == 'Normal'){
        document.execCommand('removeFormat');
    }
    else if (test == 'Bold'){
        document.execCommand('bold');                                                          
    }
    else if (test == 'Italic'){
        document.execCommand('italic');
        //console.log(document.execCommand('italic'));
    }
});
```

Here is front End code

```
<div class="user_editor_block">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active normalTxt"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Normal</a></li>
                            <li class="boldTxt"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bold</a></li>
                            <li class="italicTxt"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Italic</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="editor_text_area" contenteditable="true" id="texteditior_EXE" >
                            @php if(!empty($notes['EXE'])){ echo $notes['EXE']->note; } @endphp
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Your code looks fine only. Check here, https://codepen.io/ntamil/pen/wVMWYy

Comment: @TamilvananN it is not, it should write like a normal text after clicking on Normal button. For example, when you click on bold and italic, and after that, you click on normal, it will not write like a normal text after clicking on it.

Comment: Have you selected the text before click on the Normal?

Comment: Issue is not with the selected text. Normal is working fine selected text, but it is not writing as a normal text after clicking on Normal. I just want to have normal words written after clicking on Normal.

Comment: Without any selection you want to change the texts to normal from the place, the cursor currently pointed.

Comment: @TamilvananN yes, exactly.

Comment: Is that done in any other rich text editors like Medium editor or Wordpress wysiwyg?

Comment: No, it is not done in those editors.